# how to json php array structure in asp.net 2008

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

How can I json serialize this array structure in dotnet 3.5 ?

```
<?php

$response = array(
    'file_version' => 2,
    'files' => 
        array(
            array(
                'file_name' => 'test1.exe',
                'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/heartkey/files/test1.exe',
                'path' => 'images\filename\\'
            ),
            array(
                'file_name' => 'test2.exe',
                'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/heartkey/files/test2.exe',
                'path' => 'images\filename\\'
            ),
            array(
                'file_name' => 'test3.exe',
                'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/heartkey/files/test3.exe',
                'path' => 'images\filename\\'
            )
        ),
    'files_max_size' => 3000
);

$json =  json_encode( $response );

echo $json;
```

I found the basic way but I don't know how to represent that in vb,
I tryed with arrays and to nest the dictionary but with no luck.
My knowledege in vb.net is basic.

This is what I have:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim info As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))

        'info.Add("files", New Dictionary(Of String, String))

        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(info)

        Response.Write(serializedResult)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your PHP code is encoding your object to a Json object, is that what are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Web Forms (`.aspx`) isn't a great technology for generating `JSON` e.g. for consumption by browser AJAX calls, since it has a heavy page lifecycle and will tend to inherit a lot of ambient overhead (master pages, headers, etc) which needs to be stripped out of the response.

The preferred contemporary technology for REST / JSON type services is [Microsoft WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api), but unfortunately this won't work with .Net 3.5, only 4.0 and later.

What you can do instead is create an .ASMX Web Service and use [WebMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx) to expose your Json-Serialized string:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
Public Class WebService1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function RenderJson() As Object
        Dim theObjects() = {
            New With {
                .file_name = "test1.exe",
                .url = "http://127.0.0.1/heartkey/files/test1.exe",
                .path = "images\filename\\"
                },
            New With {
                .file_name = "test2.exe",
                .url = "http://127.0.0.1/anotherUrl",
                .path = "images\foo"
                }
            }
        Return theObjects
    End Function
```

I've used anonymous classes here, but you can also use strongly named classes to hold your data.
(I don't think I've got the shape of your javascript object quite right, but you get the idea).

**Edit** - was incorrectly returning a string :(
I've pasted a full working sample including Client Ajax call up on a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/nonnb/8d835fbdc624a76def0c)

Comment: @user3401991 It certainly compiled, although my original answer returned a string. I've uploaded a full sample as a GitHub Gist - copy all the files to the same folder and build it. There is an Ajax client example on default.aspx - watch out for the extraneous `d` [root object](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)